# how to disable javascript like media queries on maxwidth 751px

Tags: javascript, html, media-queries

i have written a webpage with a nav menu with responisve design to be able to be clickable- i want this to be gone when i turn the browser window into desktopmode, but cannot make it work, i know it should be some way to wrap it but cannot make it work`

My html:

```
<div> <a href="#" title="cart"> <img src="img/svg/cart_icon.svg" alt="cart"></a> <a href="#" title="Search"> <img src="img/svg/search_icon.svg" alt="Search"></a> <a href="#" title="Log in"> <img src="img/svg/log_in.svg" alt="Log In"></a> </div>
  <div class="logotype"><a href="index.html"> <img src="img/svg/k_logo.svg" alt="K"></a> </div>
  <div>
    <nav id="MainNavigation"> <a href="#" id="menuIcon"><img src="img/svg/menu_icon.svg" alt="Menu icon"></a> <a href="contact.html" id="contactUs"><img src="img/svg/contact_icon.svg" alt="Contact us"></a>
      <ul id="dropDownMenu">
        <li> <a href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="women.html" title="Women" id="womenId">Women</a> <a href="#" class="Sub_Menu_Link"><span class="float_Right"><img src="img/svg/Sub_menu_expander.svg" alt="+"></span></a>
          <ul class="sub_Menu">
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Coats</a> </li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Tops</a> </li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Dresses</a> </li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Trousers</a> </li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Shoes</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#" title="Men" id="menId">Men</a> <a href="#" class="Sub_Menu_Link"><span class="float_Right"><img src="img/svg/sub_menu_expander.svg" alt="+"></span></a>
          <ul class="sub_Menu">
            <li><a href="#">Coats</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Tops</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Dresses</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Trousers</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Shoes</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Sale">Sales</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <hr>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#pageHeader {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    background: white;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.logotype img {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#pageHeader img{
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    }
#pageHeader div {
    float: right;
    width: 33.33%;
}
#pageHeader div:first-of-type a {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    top:5px;
}
#pageHeader div:first-of-type a::after {
    content: "";
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
#pageHeader div::after {
    content: "";
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
#pageHeader nav>a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}
#pageHeader nav ul.open {
    display: block;
}
#pageHeader nav ul ul.open {
    display: block;
}
#pageHeader nav ul li a {
    color: #161212;
}
#pageHeader nav ul {
    display: none;
    ;
}
#pageHeader nav ul ul {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
#pageHeader nav >ul a {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#pageHeader nav ul ul a {
    padding: 0 0px 0 0px;
}
#pageHeader nav>ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 40px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
}
#pageHeader nav ul ul {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}
#pageHeader hr {
    border: 0;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 1px;
}
.Sub_Menu_Link {
    line-height: 1px;
}
.Sub_Menu_Link:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
}
.float_Right img {
    width: 10px;
}
.float_Right {
    float: right;
}
.float_Right:after {
    content: "";
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

/* förändard */
#MainNavigation ul >li a {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: #000;
}
#MainNavigation ul ul>li a {
    color: #000;
    line-height: 1px;
    font-size:.9rem;
```

Javascript

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){
"use strict";


     $("nav>a").on("click", function(){

    $("nav > ul").toggleClass("open");
    });


    $(" .Sub_Menu_Link").on("click", function(){
            $(this).next().toggleClass("open");
            });              
});
```

mediaQ

```
@media (min-width:751px) {
/*-- generic settings --*/
#pageContainer {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
/*-- main #pageHeader --*/

#pageHeader {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}

#pageHeader> div a:nth-child(3) {
    display: block;
}
    #MainNavigation{
    width:100%;

    }
    #MainNavigation ul{
        background:red;
    }

#MainNavigation >a:first-of-type {
    display: none;
}   


#dropDownMenu li:hover ul {
    display: block;

}

.sub_Menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 1;

}

#pageHeader {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 2% auto 0;
}
#contactUs {
    display: block;
}
#pageHeader div:first-of-type a {
    padding: 0px 0px 0 20px;
}
#pageHeader nav>a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "I want this to be gone". Do you mean all of the HTML that you've included above? Also, When you say desktop, are you referring to the size or non-touch devices?

If you mean size, I would just add a min-width media query and add a display: none property to the wrapping element's class or ID.

If you mean non-touch, I would use something like Modernizr to perform touch detection. If the condition is false, you could use script to add a classname to the wrapping element. that  classname would also be in your CSS with a display: none property.

EDIT: If you want to simply disable your scripts click handlers at a certain breakpoint, wrap them in a condition:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
"use strict";
    var breakPoint = 751;
    if ($(window.width() >= breakPoint) {
        $("nav>a").on("click", function(){

            $("nav > ul").toggleClass("open");
        });

        $(" .Sub_Menu_Link").on("click", function(){
            $(this).next().toggleClass("open");
        }); 
    }
});
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 0):

Can use the bootstrap media queries to detect the sizes of the devices for more details,

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp